# How to remove border(focus-indication) of input field while it is clicked

Tags: html, css

I surely know, how to remove a border, but when focus the input-field, it has a blue glowing border, which is not removable with `.field:focus{border: none}`. I'm really clueless about that and can't find anything about that.

I mean this blue border around the status-field:

->
[image: I mean this blue border]

Comment: Add `.field:focus{outline: none}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is `.field:focus{outline: none}` not `.field:focus{border: none}`

Comment: please stop editing question and adding snippet automatically ! ... pay attention to the code before, you added a PUG code to a snippet and it's not logical at all. I will flag this behavior if you continue to do so ...

Comment: Hi Temani. The PUG code was already on the original post otherwise I would not have added it to the edit, this would be illogical for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `outline: none` on focus in the input field as in the example

```css
.field1, .field2{border:none}


.field2:focus{outline: none}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="field1" placeholder="Input field1">
<br>
<input type="text" class="field2" placeholder="Input field2">
```